# NSMutableDictionary. Using an object to store an integer value

Tags: objective-c

I'd like to add instances of my custom class to a NSMutableDictionary so that each instance has a corresponding integer value? I later want to be able to retrieve the integer value using the class instance as the key.

Comment: Well, what have you tried? Does it work? If not, why not? This is sometimes called an "identity map".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `NS*Dictionary` requires objects for both keys and values.  If you want to shove an integer into a collection instance (dictionary, array, set, etc.) then you must "box" it first using `NSNumber`;  `[NSNumber numberWithInt:x];`.
2. The keys to an `NSMutableDictionary` generally need to be copyable and must have a stable hash and stable isEqual: behavior (as per the documentation).   Thus, your instances of your custom class must fulfill the `NSCopying` protocol and must properly support `hash` and `isEqual:`.   `hash` and `isEqual:` may likely "just work" if pointer equality is good enough.  Copying can be tricky.

In general, though, it is rare to have a map between instances and integral values.  Why not just add an `@property` to your class?

i.e.

```
@property int magicNumber;
```

Far more straightforward and a heck of a lot more efficient, too.

---

Note, also, that if you need to associate something with an existing instance where you can't modify the class, you should use `objc_setAssociatedObject()` and `objc_getAssociatedObject()`.  They don't require that the instance be `NSCopying`able and are relatively efficient, too (though not as efficient as an `@property`).

Comment: Thanks bbum. I agree, using the property is the way to do it. I think this dictionary information will prove useful in future.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to simply use `[myMutableDict setObject: [NSNumber numberWithInt: myInt] forKey: myClassInstance];`

At least thats what i read out of the fact that setObject takes (id) as parametertypes. :)

Comment: When I try using this I get this error: -[CCSprite copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8879590